# Linux cron bash

Tags: php, linux, bash, консоль, cron

Есть сервер php поднятый локально. (Скажу заранее в bash синтаксисе я слабоват)
Нужно что бы крон каждые 5 минут вводил в консоль следующе
cd "путь до сервера"
консольная команда
Спустя 5 минут повтор
Вот например
1)cd "/home/dev/Desktop/TestDontTach/SymphonyII/isconnect/isconnect/"
2)php bin/console datatransfer:api:fileControll
на вторую команду не обращайте внимание это мною создана на базе симфони.
Но думаю идея понятна.
Что бы каждые 5 минут этот код от сервера дергался. И выполнялась некая работа
Скажу заранее у симфони как у Ларавель как у Уай есть консольный менеджер (Или как-то он называется иначе) где можно дернуть фреймворк через консоль и он отработает. Вот такая же идея должна быть реализована через крон. Если можно объясните синтаксис как это сделать.

Comment: И в чём [проблема](https://crontab.guru/#*/5_*_*_*_*)? Что мешает [использовать](https://www.google.com/search?q=crontab+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B) поисковик?

Answer (score 2):

> Нужно что бы крон каждые 5 минут вводил в консоль следующе cd "путь до
> сервера" консольная команда

1. То, что Вы написали - не очень понятно. Сам по себе *cron* ничего никуда не выводит.
2. Можно предположить, что Вам нужно (на самом деле) **выполнить** некую консольную команду
3. Совершенно непонятно, что такое "путь до сервера". "Сервер" - это либо железяка, стоящая в какой-то комнате (с точки зрения аппаратуры), либо процесс в памяти компа, который выполняет некоторые действия по сервису клиентов. В любом случае - непонятно, что вы имеете в виду под **адресом**?

Рискну предположить, что на самом деле, Вам нужно просто раз в 5 минут запустить  некую утилиту, которая будет связываться с сервером и посылать ему запрос на обслуживание.

Тогда "путь до сервера" - это просто директория в которой располагается эта утилита. А "консольная команда" - это команда запуска этой утилиты.

Тогда, проще всего, организовать это так:

1. Создаёте скрипт на shell, в котором записываете эти две команды
2. В правах доступа ( *chmod* ) делаете скрипт исполняемым
3. С помощью *crontab -e* скажите крону, что Вы желаете выполнять этот скрипт каждые 5 минут. Как это сделать - Вам уже подсказал Daniel Protopopov.

Вот и всё...